# using random face corner attribute value for radomized color faces

Tags: modeling, shaders, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Trying to use face corner attribute to randomize mesh face colors (grayscale at the moment).
Seem not to work properly so far.

Its weird that similar concept have done using python and bmesh, worked well.

I can try and use the UV and texture but its the last thing i want do.

[image]
[image]

Comment: don't quote me on this but I *think*  attribute transfers only works in Cycles in this setup

Comment: O my,
You seem to be right !
Lets hope it will change soon.
thank you.

Comment: I also think it will be fixed in V3.0 (due in december)